# Unable to rename temporary file in SFTP remote directory

Tags: spring-integration

In continuation to the post - http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/119697-unable-to-rename-file-in-sftp-remote-directory-please-help

I am using the **sftp:outbound-channel-adapter** to upload a file into one of the sftp server. Once file is uploaded, API is unable to rename the temporary file **sample_test.pgp.writing** to **sample_test.pgp**.

Before uploading the file I verified in the sftp remote folder for file exist and remote folder was completely empty.

When I looked at the debug level log, I could see below message and it is failing at the end with the invalid path error message.

```
[main] DEBUG: com.ftp.util.FileUploadUtil -  Upload for file /sample_test.pgp triggered
[main] DEBUG: org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel - preSend on channel 'ftp.uploadgateway.request.channel', message: [Payload=/sample_test.pgp][Headers={timestamp=1406654118428, id=bbba360d-492d-4348-b2e7-566aec7f4209}]
[main] DEBUG: org.springframework.integration.filter.MessageFilter - org.springframework.integration.filter.MessageFilter@3970ae0 received message: [Payload=/sample_test.pgp][Headers={timestamp=1406654118428, id=bbba360d-492d-4348-b2e7-566aec7f4209}]
[main] DEBUG: org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel - preSend on channel 'upload.file.to.sftp', message: [Payload=/sample_test.pgp][Headers={timestamp=1406654118428, id=bbba360d-492d-4348-b2e7-566aec7f4209}]
[main] DEBUG: org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel - preSend on channel 'logger', message: [Payload=/sample_test.pgp][Headers={timestamp=1406654118428, id=bbba360d-492d-4348-b2e7-566aec7f4209}]
[main] DEBUG: org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler#0 received message: [Payload=/sample_test.pgp][Headers={timestamp=1406654118428, id=bbba360d-492d-4348-b2e7-566aec7f4209}]
[main] INFO : org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler - [Payload=/sample_test.pgp][Headers={timestamp=1406654118428, id=bbba360d-492d-4348-b2e7-566aec7f4209}]
[main] DEBUG: org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel - postSend (sent=true) on channel 'logger', message: [Payload=/sample_test.pgp][Headers={timestamp=1406654118428, id=bbba360d-492d-4348-b2e7-566aec7f4209}]
[main] DEBUG: org.springframework.integration.file.remote.handler.FileTransferringMessageHandler - org.springframework.integration.file.remote.handler.FileTransferringMessageHandler#0 received message: [Payload=/sample_test.pgp][Headers={timestamp=1406654118428, id=bbba360d-492d-4348-b2e7-566aec7f4209}]
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - Connecting to remote.sever.com port 10022
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - Connection established
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - Remote version string: SSH-2.0-SSHD
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - Local version string: SSH-2.0-JSCH-0.1.49
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - CheckCiphers: aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr,aes256-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - CheckKexes: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 is not available.
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - SSH_MSG_KEXINIT sent
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - SSH_MSG_KEXINIT received
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - kex: server: diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - kex: server: ssh-rsa
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - kex: server: aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - kex: server: aes128-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,arcfour128,arcfour256
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - kex: server: hmac-sha1,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96,hmac-sha256,hmac-sha256@ssh.com
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - kex: server: hmac-sha1,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96,hmac-sha256,hmac-sha256@ssh.com
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - kex: server: none,zlib
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - kex: server: none,zlib
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - kex: server: 
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - kex: server: 
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - kex: client: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - kex: client: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - kex: client: aes128-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-ctr,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - kex: client: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - kex: client: none
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - kex: client: none
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - kex: client: 
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - kex: client: 
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - SSH_MSG_KEXDH_INIT sent
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - expecting SSH_MSG_KEXDH_REPLY
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - ssh_rsa_verify: signature true
[main] WARN : com.jcraft.jsch - Permanently added 'remote.sever.com' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - SSH_MSG_NEWKEYS received
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - SSH_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - SSH_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - Next authentication method: publickey
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - Authentications that can continue: keyboard-interactive,password
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
[main] INFO : com.jcraft.jsch - Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
[main] DEBUG: org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool - Obtained new org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession@6e75d758.
[main] DEBUG: org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession - Initial File rename failed, possibly because file already exists. Will attempt to delete file: /inbox/sample_test.pgp and execute rename again.
[main] DEBUG: org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory - Releasing Session back to the pool.
[main] DEBUG: org.springframework.integration.util.SimplePool - Releasing org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession@6e75d758 back to the pool
[main] DEBUG: com.ftp.service.CtrlMPOJO - ERROR UPLOADING FILES EXCEPTION IS 
org.springframework.integration.MessageDeliveryException: Error handling message for file [/sample_test.pgp]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.handler.FileTransferringMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(FileTransferringMessageHandler.java:183)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:157)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:128)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:288)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.filter.MessageFilter.handleRequestMessage(MessageFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:134)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:73)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:102)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:77)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:157)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:128)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.doSend(MessagingTemplate.java:288)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.send(MessagingTemplate.java:149)
    at org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(MessagingTemplate.java:189)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.MessagingGatewaySupport.send(MessagingGatewaySupport.java:183)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invokeGatewayMethod(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:309)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.doInvoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:269)
    at org.springframework.integration.gateway.GatewayProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GatewayProxyFactoryBean.java:260)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy5.uploadFilesToFTP(Unknown Source)
    at com.ftp.util.FileUploadUtil.scanDirectoryAndUpload(FileUploadUtil.java:123)
    at com.ftp.service.CtrlMPOJO.main(CtrlMPOJO.java:160)
Caused by: org.springframework.integration.MessagingException: Failed to write to '/inbox/sample_test.pgp.writing' while uploading the file
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.handler.FileTransferringMessageHandler.sendFileToRemoteDirectory(FileTransferringMessageHandler.java:266)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.handler.FileTransferringMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(FileTransferringMessageHandler.java:172)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to delete file /inbox/sample_test.pgp; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to remove file: 2: Specified file path is invalid.
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.rename(SftpSession.java:157)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory$CachedSession.rename(CachingSessionFactory.java:137)
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.handler.FileTransferringMessageHandler.sendFileToRemoteDirectory(FileTransferringMessageHandler.java:262)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: Failed to remove file: 2: Specified file path is invalid.
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.remove(SftpSession.java:71)
    at org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.SftpSession.rename(SftpSession.java:151)
    ... 31 more
```

It works if I set the **use-temporary-file-name=false** but I do not want to set this flag incase if there is any file watcher job which may pick up incomplete file loaded at the remote server end.

**Here is the configuration i have**

```
<int:gateway id="file.upload.gateway"
    service-interface="ftp.outbound.FTPUploadGateway"
    default-request-channel="ftp.uploadgateway.request.channel"
    default-reply-channel="ftp.uploadgateway.response.channel" />

<int:filter 
    input-channel="ftp.uploadgateway.request.channel" 
    output-channel="ftp.file.exist.outbound.channel" 
    discard-channel="upload.file.to.sftp"
    expression="${ftp.outbound.remote.file.check.flag:false}">
</int:filter>

<sftp:outbound-channel-adapter id="sftpOutboundAdapter"
    session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
    channel="upload.file.to.sftp"
    charset="UTF-8"
    remote-directory="${ftp.outbound.remote.directory}"
    use-temporary-file-name="${ftp.outbound.use.temporary.filename:true}"
    remote-filename-generator-expression="${ftp.outbound.remote.filename.expression}"/>
```

Here are the property values

```
ftp.outbound.remote.file.check.flag=false
ftp.outbound.remote.directory=/inbox/
ftp.outbound.use.temporary.filename=true
ftp.outbound.remote.filename.expression=payload.getName()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please show the complete configuration.

Is your sftp user chrooted? If not `/inbox/...` is trying to manipulate the root directory on the server, and he likely doesn't have permissions for that.

Try removing the leading `/` from the remote dir.

Comment: Thanks Gary for your response. Please find configuration updated in my original post itself.

Comment: Doesn't help much without values for the properties.

Comment: No ideas; sorry. Some servers are configured to disallow rename (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25008089/spring-integration-outbound-transfer-renaming-issues).

Comment: But it works perfectly if i login manually using putty and try to rename it.

Comment: PuTTY is an `ssh` client, not an `sftp` client; does it work when you use `sftp` from the command line? Also, there is something odd about your configuration. The result of the `ls` is a `List<LSEntry>` so I don't see how your config will work without a `<splitter/>`. I would expect `payload.getName()` to fail on a payload that's a list. Can you post a DEBUG log showing the complete interaction somewhere?

Comment: Through PuTTY i logged into unix box and then used sftp command to login and rename the file in the remote sftp server.
i had filter in between but now i am directly going to outbound channel adapter from gateway. Please find the updated config file and also complete staktrace.

Comment: What you are trying to do makes no sense; sending a `List<LsEntry>` to the outbound adapter. Like I said, please post somewhere a complete `DEBUG` log.

Comment: I am sending a single file through gateway to outbound adapter. I hope you could see my latest config and also complete debug log now.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem; I suggest you turn on verbose logging on the server and see what you see; mine is shown here: https://gist.github.com/garyrussell/2e9b9ac542b9fdcda3fb

Comment: Its 3rd party sftp server and i need to work with their IT team to enable VERBOSE. Meanwhile i tested with our own internal SFTP server and it worked without any issue. Not sure why it is not working for vendor SFTP server though it works when we do manually through sftp command. Thanks for your help and i will come back to this thread if problem still exists.